# Method PATCH is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API

Tags: rest-api

I'm using PATCH `/composite/sobjects` URI as stated in the [`REST API Developer Guide`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_update.htm).

But I'm receiving this error:

> Method PATCH is not defined in RFC 2068 and is not supported by the Servlet API

The response is immediate. My request body is JSON. The response gives no hints that body is malformed.

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: which rest client are you using?

Comment: playframework WSClient.  Debugger shows that it is setting request method to PATCH.

Comment: I was able to do this via 'Postman' and Salesforce workbench. It can happen that your rest client does not support PATCH

Comment: mind pasting, your full uri?

Comment: `https://myorg.salesforce.cm/services/data/v44.0/composite/sobjects`

Comment: thanks.  I misread docs.  I did not prepend `/services/data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use Composite API, you have to use full URL including `services/data/vxx.0`

eg:

```
https://myorg.salesforce.com/services/data/v44.0/composite/sobjects
```